# Groupby and divide count of grouped elements in pyspark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below. I want to do `groupby` and count of `category` column in `data frame`

```
df.show()
+--------+----+
|category| val|
+--------+----+
|    cat1|  13|
|    cat2|  12|
|    cat2|  14|
|    cat3|  23|
|    cat1|  20|
|    cat1|  10|
|    cat2|  30|
|    cat3|  11|
|    cat1|   7|
|    cat1|   8|
+--------+----+


res = df.groupBy('category').count()

res.show()

+--------+-----+
|category|count|
+--------+-----+
|    cat2|    3|
|    cat3|    2|
|    cat1|    5|
+--------+-----+
```

I am getting my desired result. Now I want to calculate the `average` of category. `data frame` has records for 3 days. I want to calculate average of count for these 3 days.

The result I want is below. I basically want to do `count/no.of.days`

```
+--------+-----+
|category|count|
+--------+-----+
|    cat2|    1|
|    cat3|    1|
|    cat1|    2|
+--------+-----+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupby('category').agg((F.count('val') / 3).alias('average'))
```

Comment: yes this is what I want. A small doubt when I divide `5/3` I am getting `1.666667` Is there a way to round them to nearest number for exampl2 `5/3` to `1.67` or may be `2` even better

Comment: `F.round(F.count('val') / 3, 2)` instead of `F.count('val') / 3`, you can consult http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions for more details of the range of function you can use in spark